# Eulerian graphs proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let G=(V,E) be a connex graph. Color it's edges randomly with red/blue.

-prove that there exists an Eulerian circuit, without any two adjacent edges of the same color.. only if for any `v` vertex of G the number of incident blue edges is equal to the number of red ones.

-if G is complete and `x,y,z` are three distinct vertices prove that, if there is a path without consecutive edges of the same color from `x` to `y` passing through `z`,  then there is a path with the same property that has `xz` as the first edge or `zy` as the last edge.

Please help me by at least providing some suitable references that may help me solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These probably should be comments but I don't have sufficient reputation.

Hint for problem 1: If there are an equal number of red and blue edges at each vertex, what does that tell you about the parity of the degree of each vertex?

Hint for problem 2: If you have a path from x to y passing through z, can you use the fact that the graph is complete to find another path that fits the alternating condition?

Comment: hint2 is ok. Not sure about hint 1.. I think I'll still have to prove that my path has no consecutive edges of the same color.

Comment: my mistake, I misread the question. Try inducting on the number of red/blue edges at a vertex.